# Getting my array[1] to get values from another array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get my array to get values from another array of the same type. 
Here's my code that works

```
public class Skill {
    //....variables
}    

public Skill[]    allSkills; 

void Start () 
{
    allSkills = new Skill[5];    // this is a class of array
}

void GetArray ()
{
   string blah = PlayerPrefs.GetString("CatSkills");
   allSkills = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Skill[]>(blah);

    // the above can also be translated as
   Skill[] skill;
   allSkills = skill;
}
```

While the above works, it only applies the values on allSkills[0]. And after I deleted my PlayerPrefs, it turns my allSkill's array size to null.

How do I make it maintain my array size and apply the values to 'allSkills[1]'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer. This is for whoever that wants to know.

```
public class Skill {
    //....variables
}    

public List<Skill> allSkills    = new List<Skill>();
public Skill[] skillArray;

void GetArray ()
{
   string blah = PlayerPrefs.GetString("CatSkills");
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Skill>>(blah).CopyTo(skillArray, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the new array (`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Skill[]>(blah)`) to `allArray`, so the reference to old instance is replaced by new instance! if you wanna fill the old array with values of new array just use `CopyTo` method:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Skill[]>(blah).CopyTo(allSkills, 0);
```

Note that this way you can't apply all values to allSkills[1], because it's a one dimensional array. For that you can use a two dimensional array if you want an array of arrays!

**Edit:** If you wanna use an array of arrays you have two options, use `jagged array` or a simple `two dimensional array`, with jagged array you have to specify the number of rows but the number of columns can vary. But if you know the number of columns then go for a simple `two dimensional array`, though I recommend you to use `List` instead if `Array`. Here is `jagged array` code sample:

```
public Skill[][] = new Skill[5][]; // Instantiate a jagged array with 5 rows

...

allSkills[1] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Skill[]>(blah);
```

Comment: 'CopyTo' doesn't exist here..
How do I go about the two dimensional array?

Comment: Why it doesn't exist?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the shortcut doesn't appear and I'm getting a NullReference error

Comment: if DeserializeObject return a Skill[] array then it should have CopyTo method, but if you're getting NullReference then check the return value and if not null then call CopyTo.

Comment: I tried to change to List. CopyTo is appearing now. But an error also appeared. 

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Skill[]>(blah).CopyTo(allSkills, 0);`

That was my code. Next is the error.

`Argument '#1' cannot convert 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SkillScript.Skill>' expression to type 'System.Array'`

Comment: sigh.... List and Arrays is killing me.. I've spent the whole day on this one stupid line

Comment: with CopyTo you don't have to assign it to allSkills. Then when you used List<Skill> you have to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Skill>>(blah) instead.

Comment: I suggest you to read these: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx

Comment: Oops, sorry, forgot about those two lines you mentioned.
I still have this error.. and I have no idea why this appears

`Argument '#1' cannot convert 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SkillScript.Skill>' expression to type 'SkillScript.Skill[]'`

Comment: I've read up on those links and watched a few videos about Lists. Your code `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Skill>>(blah).CopyTo(allSkills);` is supposed to work... But it just keeps giving me this error `Argument '#1' cannot convert 'SkillScript.Skill' expression to type 'SkillScript.Skill[]'`

Comment: All right, I managed to solve it thanks to you telling me about List and CopyTo. I had to create another array and use that array for CopyTo. I'd upvote you for helping, but I don't have enough rep. I'll post my answer after 8 hours since the system doesn't let me now.